# Why am I getting a 409 Conflict deleting a document through Couchbase Sync Gateway?

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

Can anyone explain to me why I'm getting this response trying to delete a document?

```
curl -X DELETE --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:4985/mydb/uprofile:testing'
```

When I run this, I get:

```
{
    "error": "conflict",
    "reason": "Document exists"
}
```

How come?

Answer (score 0):

A conflict usually occurs when two writers are offline and save a different revision of the same document.

As quick fix first get document from syn-gateway and

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://localhost:4985/uprofile%3Atesting/mydb?attachments=false&revs=false&show_exp=false'
```

Then get _rev value from document.. Then try delete as following

```
curl -X DELETE --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://localhost:4985/uprofile%3Atesting/mydb?rev={_rev value}'
```

I am sure this will work, 
but for permanent solution where to resolve conflicts dynamically check documentation https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/guides/sync-gateway/resolving-conflicts/index.html